# Hiding or removing some data from XML response in WSO2 API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 to expose APIs internally. The API works as a pass-through proxy (or gateway) that forwoard the request to a back-end-service and adding just some headers. 
Now, i want to hide some information when intercepting the response from the back-end plateform.

I tried filter mediator but i'm not sure that i'm on the right way.

Below an example of what i want to do.

Actual response (as-is):

```html
<member>
<name>ABC</name>
<value>abc</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>XYZ</name>
<value>xyz</value>
</member>
```

Wished response (to be sent to the client after remove/hide actions):

```html
<member>
<name>ABC</name>
<value>abc</value>
</member>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the Enrich mediator to modify the body.

As per your code snippet enrich mediator can be as below and can be added right after calling the endpoint.

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="true" xpath="$body//member[1]"/>
  <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

In the above enrich mediator, it will retrieve the first `member` tag of the response body and it will be set as the body.

You can refer the Enrich mediator documentation [1] for further reference.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Enrich+Mediator

Comment: Hi there, thanks Saad for the help. I just want to ask if i can use the enrich mediator at the start of the out sequence.

Comment: Yes you can have enrich mediator at the beginning of the outsequnece

Comment: Hey there, If this worked can this be accepted as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

It worked me thank you. But can i do the same action by refering to the value of the member? in other words, can i put this code:

```html
 <enrich>
  <source clone="true" xpath="$body//name[ABC]"/>
  <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```